# BASH - using a column of awk inside system

Tags: bash

In Bash I'm trying to get the process with most %CPU. Once i get it, i'm using awk to evaluate if the process must be killed or just change it's nice. Once i get the process, here's what i'm trying to do :

```
awk -v awkmax="$CPU_MAX" '
{ 
  if( $3 > awkmax && $4 < 15 ) { 
    system("renice "$4"+5 -p "$1"")
  } 
  else if ( $3 > awkmax && $4 == 15 ) { 
    system("kill -9 "$1"")
    print "The process $1 has been killed.\n" 
  } 
}'
```

where `$3` is pcpu, `$4` is the nice value and `$1` is the pid.

My problem is here:

```
system("renice "$4"+5 -p "$1"")
```

it doesn't work because of the `"$4"+5`, which is the actual nice of the process plus 5.

How can i pass that value to renice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have some quoting issues, the first `system` call should be:

```
system("renice " $4 + 5 " -p " $1)
```

And the second:

```
system("kill -9 " $1)
```

Space is the string concatenation operator in `awk`.

A note on `kill -9`: it's better to start with less severe signals before resorting to `-9`, as this doesn't let the process do any cleaning up after it self, IIRC, start with SIGHUP (`-1`), then SIGINT (`-2`), then SIGTERM (`-15`), if none of these makes the process quit, then use SIGKILL (`-9`).

Comment: `SIGTERM` is the default for kill and usually what you want to start with.

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably use:

```
awk -v awkmax="$CPU_MAX" '
{ 
  if ($3 > awkmax && $4 < 15) {
    renice = $4 + 5 
    system("renice " renice " -p "$1"")
  } 
  else if ($3 > awkmax && $4 == 15) { 
    system("kill -9 " $1)
    print "The process $1 has been killed.\n" 
  } 
}'
```

`awk` is unusual in using adjacent values with no explicit operator to indicate concatenation.